# Find a 6 letter word by its parts

Tags: riddle, english

I am a 6 letter word

> Letters 6-5-2 spell out a drink
>
> Letters 4-5-2-3 spell out a fruit
>
> Letters 1-2-6 spell out a pet
>
> Letters 3-2-6 spell out a pest
>
> The pest above often gets eaten by 1-2-6
>
> 1-2-6 is a 4-5-6 is a universal truth

**What Am I?**

(This puzzle is taken from my website. There's a link in my profile.)

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! If this puzzle came from another site (Riddle Me Daily?), could you please add a link for attribution? Thanks!

Comment: do these type of puzzles have a name? (and a ready solver!)

Comment: @boboquack source: https://www.riddlemedaily.com/i-am-6-letter-word-letters-6-5-2-spell-drink/

Comment: Actually, in the specific case where someone posts a puzzle from *their own* external source, we actually prefer them *not* to link to it. See https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4340/how-not-to-be-a-spammer-redux for a pretty good statement of site policy on this.

Comment: Reasons why we say *not* to link to your own site even though we say you *should* provide links when taking other people's puzzles: (1) the issue of plagiarism doesn't arise in this case, so you don't need to link to provide credit, and (2) we want to minimize the incentive for self-promotion because PSE is not meant to be an advertising tool.

Comment: Thanks for the kind words @GarethMcCaughan Will sick to policies :)

Comment: Good to hear. Another one to take note of: we also say "Don't create an excessive number of self-promoting posts". I'm sorry to say that two in three hours is certainly excessive :-). I guess the main principle is this: If it looks like you're here to contribute to the community, and it happens that every now and then you promote your site in doing so, that's OK. If it looks like you're here to promote your site, and any benefit to the community is incidental, that's not OK.

Answer (score 22):

You are a

> Carpet
>  6-5-2: tea
>  4-5-2-3: pear
>  1-2-6: cat, which eats 3-2-6: rat
>  1-2-6 is a cat which is a pet (4-5-6).

Comment: I question the universality of that truth! :-)